# MapView search places are visible on wrong co-ordinates

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview

I have develop an application in iOS 7.0. I have a map view in which user can see search results in map by means of annotation pins.

I have used custom annotation for that, For the first time annotations were placed at correct co ordinates. I mean at user location co ordinates were place at correct position.

But if i scroll map and search for location then it shows me annotation at wrong co ordinates.

Below is my code when user search any thing in map. (e.g Hotels, Museum, Restaurants)

```
- (void) searchForPlace:(NSString *) keyWord {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    [self.activityView setHidden:NO];

    [self.txtSearch resignFirstResponder];
    [self.txtSearch setEnabled:NO];

    MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = keyWord; // @"restaurant"
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(.1, .1);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    request.region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span);
    MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [search startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
         [self.txtSearch setEnabled:YES];
         [self removeMapOverlay];

         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
         [self.activityView setHidden:YES];
         if (!error) {
             // Result found
             @try {

                 if (response.mapItems && [response.mapItems count] > 0) {

                     for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems) {
                         MKPlacemark *placeMark = item.placemark;

                         // Address details
                         NSDictionary *address = placeMark.addressDictionary;
                         NSString *titleString = @"";
                         NSString *subtitleString = @"";
                         NSString *name = @"";
                         NSString *Thoroughfare = @"";
                         NSString *State = @"";
                         NSString *City = @"";
                         NSString *Country = @"";

                         name = [address objectForKey:@"Name"] ? [address objectForKey:@"Name"] : @"";
                         Thoroughfare = [address objectForKey:@"Thoroughfare"] ? [address objectForKey:@"Thoroughfare"] : @"";
                         State = [address objectForKey:@"State"] ? [address objectForKey:@"State"] : @"";
                         City = [address objectForKey:@"City"] ? [address objectForKey:@"City"] : @"";
                         Country = [address objectForKey:@"Country"] ? [address objectForKey:@"Country"] : @"";

                         titleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", name, Thoroughfare];
                         subtitleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", State, City, Country];

                         CustomAnnotation *annotation = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:titleString subTitle:subtitleString detailURL:item.url location:placeMark.location.coordinate];
                         [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
                     }
                     [self mapView:self.mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:YES];
                 }

             }
             @catch (NSException *exception) {
                 NSLog(@"Exception :%@",exception.description);
             }

         } else {
             NSLog(@"No result found.");
         }
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because of this line:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
```

What here problem is you are doing search request for `region` around your user location.

You need to set center co ordinates `region` of `MKMapView`. So that region for the search area will be consider where ever you scroll in map.

Change above line with this and check your search result.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = self.mapView.centerCoordinate;
```

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thanks :)